# If I erase all content and settings will I lose my contacts?

Tags: ios

If I erase all content and settings will I lose my contacts?

Comment: Stack exchange doesn't work well when there are multiple questions. Please edit your post to concentrate on one issue, & provide as much detail as you can. As it stands, there is little to go on.

Comment: I've removed the second question from your question. Feel free to search for an answer to the other question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on where the contacts are stored.

- If the contacts are stored **in iCloud**, you will **not** lose the contacts. Log in to iCloud and the contacts will be restored.
- If the contacts are **on your SIM card**, you will **not** lose the contacts. You can re-import the contacts from your SIM card.
- If the contacts are stored **on your device**, you **will** lose the contacts.